# How to set the detailView as a list of element to my application?

Tags: ios, tableview

I have a tableView in my application and i wanna that the detailView being a list of elements (tableView too) but i don't know how to implement this, can any one help me and thanks a lot.!

Answer (score 1):

you must be use section in tableview..

Comment: my problem is i can't make my detailView as a list of data (the detailView is a table view )